# Sencha Touch 2 - Format number on itemTpl

Tags: numbers, format, sencha-touch-2

How can I format a number inside a itemTpl?

Example:

`'<div style="font-size: 9px;">Total: $ {total}</div>' <= This number {total} must be 100.00, but appears just 100`

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.. if you got the answer, you need to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a member function of your `XTemplate`:

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<div style="font-size: 9px;">Total: $ {[this.formatTotal(values.total)]}</div>',
    formatTotal: function(total) {
        return //formattedTotal
    }
)
```

Learn more here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

Answer (score 0):

As @kevhender said you can use [Ext.XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) and [toFixed](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) javascript method for formatting.

More specific

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
     '<div style="font-size: 9px;">Total: $ {[this.totalFormat(values.total)]}</div>',{
        totalFormat : function(total) {
          return total.toFixed(2);
      }
})
```